# Mix 2 array data with a certain limit from both array with a regular interval

Tags: php, arrays

I am facing a problem in combining 2 arrray data on a regular interval.
i am trying `alot and also tried man things,but not able to solve properly.`
I have two arrays.
 let us assume

```
arr1[] = //contains some data
arr2[] = //contains other data
```

now i want to create a third array, which contains first 3 elements of first array and 7 other elements of 2nd array. i am tried and still trying many things but it is not working for me.
the output should be like this.

```
arr3[] = (arr1[0],arr1[1],arr[2],arr2[1],arr2[2],arr2[3],arr2[4],arr2[5],arr2[6],arr2[7],arr1[4],arr1[5],arr[6],arr2[8]..................);
```

Can anyone help me on this??

Huge Thanks in Advance :)

lastly this is working for me aprox. but still having some logical issues. can any one help me to resolve this.i can not able to find to actual cause with reason.

```
// Here are 2 arrays

$search_data_p = array('p1','p2','p3','p4','p5','p6','p7','p8','p9','p10','p11','p12','p13','p14','p15','p16','p17','p18','p19','p20');
$search_data_f = array('f1','f2','f3','f4','f5','f6','f7','f8','f9','f10','f11','f12','f13','f14','f15','f16','f17','f18','f19','f20');
                $f = 0;
                $s = 0;
                    for($i = 1 ; $i <= 40; $i++)
                    {   
                        if($i <= (3 + $s))
                        {
                            if($i <= 3)
                            { 
                                 $final_data[$i]=$search_data_p[$i - 1];
                            }else
                            { 
                                $final_data[$i]=$search_data_p[$i - 8];
                            }
                        }else{
                            if($i <= (10 + $s))
                            {   
                                if($i <= 10)
                                {
                                    $final_data[$i]=$search_data_f[$i-4];
                                }else
                                { 
                                    $final_data[$i]=$search_data_f[$i-7];
                                }
                            }
                         if($i === ($s + 10))
                           {    
                             $s =$s + 10;
                            }
                       }
                    }
                echo '<pre>';
                print_r($final_data);
```

It is giving me following output

Array
(
    [1] => p1
    [2] => p2
    [3] => p3
    [4] => f1
    [5] => f2
    [6] => f3
    [7] => f4
    [8] => f5
    [9] => f6
    [10] => f7
    [11] => p4
    [12] => p5
    [13] => p6
    [14] => f8
    [15] => f9
    [16] => f10
    [17] => f11
    [18] => f12
    [19] => f13
    [20] => f14
    [21] => p14
    [22] => p15
    [23] => p16
    [24] => f18
    [25] => f19
    [26] => f20
    [27] => 
    [28] => 
    [29] => 
    [30] => 
    [31] => 
    [32] => 
    [33] => 
    [34] => 
    [35] => 
    [36] => 
    [37] => 
    [38] => 
    [39] => 
    [40] => 
)

why the loop is not assigning data after. loop is executing 40 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue by my own.
here is the code.

```
<?php
$paid = array('p1','p2','p3','p4','p5','p6','p7','p8','p9','p10','p11','p12','p13','p14','p15','p16','p17','p18','p19','p20','p21','p22','p23','p24');
$free = array('f1','f2','f3','f4','f5','f6','f7','f8','f9','f10','f11','f12','f13','f14','f15','f16','f17','f18','f19','f20','f21','f22','f23','f24','f25','f26','f27','f28','f29','f30','f31','f32','f33','f34','f35','f36','f37','f38','f39','f40','f41','f42','f43','f44','f45','f46','f47','f48','f49','f40');

$f = 0;
$s = 0;
$k = 1;
$n = 6;
for($i = 0 ; $i < 80; $i++)
{
if($i < (3 + $s))
{
if($i < 3)
{ 
 $final_data[$i]=$paid[$i];
}else
{ 
 $m = $i-(7*$k);
$final_data[$i]=$paid[$m];
}
}else{
if($i < (10 + $s))
{
if($i < 10)
{
$final_data[$i]=$free[$i-3];
}else
{ 
$final_data[$i]=$free[$i-$n];
}
}
}
if($i == ($s + 9))
{   
$s =$s + 10;
if($i >= 18)
{
$k += 1;
$n  += 3;
}

}


                    }
// avoiding null values in case of null data
$new_arr = array();

for($i=0;$i < count($final_data);$i++)
{
if($final_data[$i] != '')
    $new_arr[] = $final_data[$i];
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($new_arr);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe not the perfect solution but it works

```
   for($i = 0 , $i < count($arr2), $i++) {
    if($i < 3){
     $arr3[]=$arr1[$i];
   }else {
     if($i < 10){
        $arr3[]=$arr2[$i]
     }
   }
```

Comment: just here not a 10 elements then it only assigned 1 time 3 elements but always assigned after arr2[] elements.

Comment: john i am saying that just consider a scenario. let us assume array length is 23 (sum of both array count) .then when loop will execute it will assign first 3 elements of arr1[] into an arr3[] .but when $i will be 11 then it will assign still 2nd array elements .

Comment: we have to maintain both array values and preserver there keys through loops

Comment: @user3351494 you could just add another if $i < 10 to prevent that